# How does SASS know about a variable that is not defined?

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I have this mixin:

```
@mixin respond($breakpoint) {
    @if $breakpoint == phone {
        @media (max-width: 37.5em) { @content };
    }
}
```

And this mixin is used like this:

```
  @include respond(phone) {
    font-size: 50%;
  }
```

What I don't understand is how does SASS know what the variable `phone` is?

What is being passed when you call `@include respond(phone)` and similarly what is being compared when this happens? `@if $breakpoint == phone`

So what is phone? I don't see anywhere in the code that defines phone as a variable..

But looking at the compiled css, it seems to work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phone is just a reference for specific breakpoint, you could also type anything instead of `phone`, the magic happens inside of `if` statement where you define what is `phone` refering to:

```
@media (max-width: 37.5em) { @content };
```

To break it down:
You pass a phone to respond here:

```
@include respond(phone) {…}
```

Then in the `mixin` respond you are checking if the `$breakpoint` is equal to `phone` or whatever you have written in the `@include respond()`. If it’s true, it will go inside of if statement.

For example, you could do something like this:

```
@include respond(something) {}

@mixin respond($breakpoint) {
    @if $breakpoint == something {
        …do what you want
    }
}
```

Comment: I still don't understand, what am i passing when i say `@include respond(phone)`? It looks like phone refers to nothing? `@mixin respond($breakpoint)` expects an argument to be passed to it, in this case $breakpoint but what does passing in phone mean?

Comment: The phone is so to say just a word that represents a breakpoint so you can access it easier. It's easier to write a `phone` then write a @media query each time you need one. So you are passing whatever is inside `@include respond(phone)`to `@content`... Is that more clear now?

Comment: [Here](https://css-tricks.com/approaches-media-queries-sass/) is a good article about different ways of using media queries with scss.

Comment: Your updated answer was clear to me! Hey thanks buddy!